# Show customer address from S.O. on delivery slip

Tags: odoo-15

In Odoo v15 I am trying to display customer address from Sales Order on delivery slip (report - printed document).

Customer and delivery address are not the same on sales order and on report when I print delivery slip by default it is showing me the same information for contact and delivery address. I tested this on runbot in v16 also - it is strange.

To solve this I inherited 'stock.report_delivery_document' and tried to replace div with name 'partner_header' inside of which should customer address display with this code:

```
 <xpath expr="//div[@name='partner_header']" position="replace">
     <span class="pt-5" t-esc="o.partner_id.name"/><br />
 </xpath>
```

The code is giving me info from delivery address, not from Customer that is on Sales Order.

Please help - sorry if creating module is not the way to do it.

Comment: If there is no direct relation to the contact you want in deliveries. The delivery has an origin where you can search sales for that origin name and retrieve the contact

Comment: How can I retrieve the contact address from related Sales Order? Can you please help me with the python file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution - in inherited "stock.report_delivery_document" I accessed customer address from related Sales Order using o.sale_id.partner_id

Here is the code - used contact widget to format it:

```
<div t-field="o.sale_id.partner_id" t-options-widget="'contact'"/>
```